# Vertical Float Button

Tags: html, css

[image]

I m trying to make vertical float button for my website but this is what I m getting. **Text is outside box**

CSS

```
#feedback { 
  height: 104px; 
  width: 104px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 40%; 
  z-index: 999;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

#feedback a { 
  display: block; 
  background: #f00; 
  height: 15px; 
  width: 70px; 
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: #fff; 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 17px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
  border-left: solid 1px #333;
  border-right: solid 1px #fff;
}

#feedback a:hover { 
  background: #06c; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="feedback">
  <a href="/feedback_url/">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the height and it will be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `height: 15px` is what that causes this issue for you. Everything is fine otherwise. Remove the `height` from `#feedback a` and it will be alright.

```css
#feedback a {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  height: 15px; /* Remove this... */
```

Height of an element is generally set by the content and the `line-height`. If you try to manually set, it goes out of context with the contents. That's what just happened now.

Comment: Thanks!! Code is Working